# JAWS Reads seperate divs together, how to prevent this?

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria, jaws-screen-reader

I am testing out a web application and notice something very strange.

Say I have a parent `div` with a `tabindex="0"` so the user can focus it via keyboard.

```
<div tabindex="0">
  <div>
    <span>34</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>43</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

If I have the above layout, it will read "Three thousand four hundred forty three" rather than "Thirty Four" "Fourty Three". Is there anything I can do here to prevent the merging of these numbers? I'm shocked that it's doing this in the first place considering they are in separate inner divs AND spans.

Comment: try putting a `&nbsp;` between the two

Comment: What version of JAWS are you using?  I attempted this on a test page in my environment with NVDA screen reader and it read correctly (said 34, then said 43), so it might be a JAWS thing.  If an older version, that could explain it.  But, you would always try wrapping the spans in <p> or using aria landmarks / role attributes to help the cause.

Comment: I'm using JAWS 16. I found that @unobf's solution worked just find for reading purposes and didn't really impact the layout of my page though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting a `&nbsp;` between the two `spans` is a viable solution to this.